# Delete a pointer to a pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem:

There is a pointer: `double **p = 0;`
I must do this: [task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNnYd.jpg)

Is it correct?

```
int main {
    double **p = new double*; 
    double value = 2;
    double *index = new double; 
    index = &value; 
    p = &index; 
    p = new double*;
    index = new double;
    delete p;
    delete index; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to initialize the pointers with `new something` in your code... that's just memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm operating off the assumption you are just playing with pointers for educational purposes and have no plans on using this code for anything important. If you are planning on using this, stop and rethink your algorithm. There is almost certainly no need for this much dynamic allocation and pointer-play.

Going though the code line-by-line:

```
01 double **p = new double*; // OK
02 double value = 2;
03 double *index = new double; // OK
04 index = &value; // BAD. memory leak. Lost pointer to the allocation from 03
05 p = &index; // BAD. memory leak. Lost pointer to the allocation from 01
06 p = new double*; // OK. pointer to local overwritten, and local will self-destruct
07 index = new double; // OK. pointer to local overwritten
08 delete p; // OK. deletes allocation from 06 
09 delete index; // OK. deletes allocation from 07
10 return 0;
```

## EDIT

Just noticed the link to the problem statement. You should make that a bit more obvious. All you need is:

```
double value = 2;
double * valuep = &value;
double ** p = &valuep;
```

That, and according to Lennon and McCartney, love.

Comment: @DeanoMachino Thank you a lot for your answer. I ve used your advice, but i still have one more question: Can I delete pointer, if the pointer was  initiliazatied without new.

Comment: No. You can only `delete` that which was `new`ed. If you `new`ed an array ( eg.  `new int [10];`), you ill have to `delete[]` it. In some  cases you will also find `malloc` and `free` in older code. Avoid these as they do not do everything that `new` and `delete` do.

Comment: @DeanoMachino Thank you so much for your help!